# 2D array to Property Store, then Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an array `ColAarr` that I want to store.

```
ColAarr.push([shtData[2][1]]);

var ScriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); 
var xColAarr = JSON.stringify(ColAarr);
Logger.log(xColAarr);

ScriptProperties.setProperties(xColAarr);
```

When I try to setPreperties, I get the error

> Exception: Invalid argument

The xColAarr Log Result shows

> [["Train Station"],["Train Station"],["Bus Station"]]

This explains the error as only a string can be sent to the Property Store.
But should I be using `JSON.stringify` differently?

I haven't got as far as seeing if my code to repopulate the array before putting the data onto the sheet works.
Any advice most appreciated.

```
ColAarr.push([JSON.parse(ScriptProperties.getProperty('xColAarr'))]);
ResultFile.getRange('A'+GlobLastRow+':A'+(ColAarr.length+GlobLastRow-1)).setValues(ColAarr);
ScriptProperties.deleteAllProperties();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `setProperties()` of your script is required to be modified. `properties` of `setProperties(properties)` is an object including the keys and values. When you want to use `xColAarr` as the value, please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var ColAarr = [["Train Station"],["Train Station"],["Bus Station"]];  // Sample value from your question.

var ScriptProperties = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
var xColAarr = JSON.stringify(ColAarr);
Logger.log(xColAarr);

ScriptProperties.setProperties({key1: xColAarr});  // Modified

// When you want to retrieve the value of xColAarr, please use the following script.
var retrievedValue = JSON.parse(ScriptProperties.getProperty("key1"));
console.log(retrievedValue)
```

#### Reference:

- [setProperties(properties)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties#setProperties(Object))